# Would you need an "s" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, usage

> From mega trade shows to small individualized meeting.

Would it be ok to write "meeting" with no "s", or it would be more accurate with an "s" just to make it plural and go parallel with trade shows?

Answer (score 2):

You could write it without an *s*, but you would need an article:

> From mega trade shows to **a** small individualised meeting.

Whether you put *meeting* in singular or plural, your sentence has a different meaning. If you mean to say that it goes from **multiple** mega trade shows to **one** individualised meeting, you put *meeting* in the singular form. However, if you mean to say that it goes from multiple mega trade shows to an equal amount of (or even a different amount, but still more than one) meetings, then add the *s* for the plural form:

> From mega trade shows to small individualised meeting**s**.

Comment: I agree with @Sander 's comment.  I would only add that the sentence sounds better if you are consistent: either "from mega trade shows to meetings" or "from a mega trade show to a meeting".  if you switch between the plural and the singular, it sounds a little strange, since there's no obvious reason why you're doing it.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my issue. I will rectify the problem.